# Relocate Pagefile.sys to address availability error "Drives are running out of free space"

Tags: 2016, windows-server-2012-r2, minrole

Scenario: Production environment, SharePoint 2016 MinRole Farm, 1 Application with Search Server and 1 Front-End with Distributed Cache. On App server, getting Availability Error

"Available drive space is less than twice the value of physical memory."

I am considering relocating Pagefile.sys to the D drive (80 GB).
Researching and found this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2014/07/09/recommendations-for-page-files-on-sharepoint-servers/

I want to know if someone has tried this approach of relocating pagefile.sys as a way to get free space on the C drive (80 GB size) on SharePoint 2016 and get rid of this Availability error in Central Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable the health analyzer rule. Monitor your disk free space via other means. The rule is nonsensical given it needs 5*RAM for free disk space, which doesn't make sense except for a full dump with a BSOD. This isn't the default for Windows (it takes a mini dump instead).

Comment: Thank you @Trevor Seward for answering, but this is not the 5*RAM rule, this is the other one that is looking for 2*RAM. Do you recommend disabling as well as for the 5*RAM?

Comment: Disable both...